# How to call a PHP function on HTML form submission?

Tags: php

I am having some trouble sending data from a form to a function

Here is my form:

```
echo "<form id='AddCompany' action='' method=post>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th colspan='2'>Opret nyt firma</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<td>Firma Navn:<td><input type='text' name='Name' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Adresse:<td><input type='text' name='Address' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Postnr.:<td><input type='text' name='Zipcode' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>By:<td><input type='text' name='City' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Land:<td><input type='text' name='Country' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Tlf:<td><input type='text' name='Phone' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Slogan:<td><input type='text' name='Slogan' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Catch All Email:<td><input type='text' name='Email' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Logo 1:<td><input type='FILE' name='Logo1' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Lille  Logo:<td><input type='FILE' name='SmallLogo' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td>Logo 2:<td><input type='FILE' name='Logo2' /></td>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Opret Firma' />";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "</td></tr>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
```

I want to send the data to this function

```
function insertRecord ($fieldarray)
    {
        $this->errors = array();

        global $dbconnect, $query;
        $dbconnect = db_connect($this->dbname) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

        $fieldlist = $this->fieldlist;
        foreach ($fieldarray as $field => $fieldvalue) {
            if (!in_array($field, $fieldlist)) {
                unset ($fieldarray[$field]);
            } // if
        } // foreach

        $query = "INSERT INTO $this->tablename SET ";
        foreach ($fieldarray as $item => $value) {
            $query .= "$item='$value', ";
        } // foreach
        $query = rtrim($query, ', ');
        return;
    } // insertRecord
```

I just realised you might need this bit of code also:

```
class Company extends Default_Table
{
    // additional class variables go here
    function __construct ()
    {
        $this->tablename       = 'Company';
        $this->dbname          = 'oop';
        $this->rows_per_page   = 15;
        $this->fieldlist       = array('ID', 'Name', 'Address','Zipcode','City','Country','Phone','Slogan','CatchAllEmail','Logo1','LogoSmall','Logo2');
        $this->fieldlist['ID'] = array('pkey' => 'y');
    } // __construct
} // Company
```

Where do I call the function and which variables should I send with it?

I have tried `onclick=insertRecord()` which doesn't seem to work, and I am thinking it is because I need to insert a variable, which I think needs to be an array of the form data as the function is declared with an array.

As you can see I am pretty much a tenderfoot at this.

I have found out the following:

If I echo my $query after the foreach loop in the insertRecord function I see the query like so:
    INSERT INTO Company SET Name='1', Address='2', Zipcode='3', City='4', Country='5', Phone='6', Slogan='7', CatchAllEmail='8', Logo1='', LogoSmall='', Logo2=''

However still nothing is being inserted, I have tried this on 2 servers and with users I know have insert rights however nothing is getting inserted.

Comment: Just an tip: you can do 1 echo  you dont have to type it 70 times.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after I had typed it 70 times :-) thanks for the tip though :-)

Comment: Is this function a part of an object? If so, you can use a __construct method to insert your post data into the function. onclick methods are for javascript functions and wont work with php functions directly.

Comment: Yes, it is part of the class Default_Table and it is a Company that I am trying to insert

Comment: cutebabs please see my reply under your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use function but you can do like,
 remove `action =""`  from `<form>`.

then check like,

```
    if($_POST){
     //your function logic
    // get variable data like 
      echo $_POST["Name"];
    }
```

Enjoy!

Comment: cutebabs, I get the output in echo $_POST["Name"]; but I am not inserting the data in the database. So I need to do something like $cmpny = new Company();
$cmpny->insertRecord($_POST); I guess inside the if statement but that doesn't work.

Comment: I have found out that I do actually call the function and send the data to the function but nothing gets inserted, so now I guess it is a question of why it doesn't actually insert it even though it receives all the data

Answer (score 1):

Please take this in the most friendly way, I recommend that you pick up a book or read a tutorial about PHP/MySQL/HTML/JavaScript.
I'll do my best to explain this without going outside the scope of this Q&A site.

What you have in the first part of the code is an HTML form `echo`ed by a PHP script, so the HTML form is now in the client's browser.

What you're trying to do with `onclick=insertRecord()` is binding an event handler written in PHP (server side) to an event fired in browser (client side).

**How to solve your problem?**

You need to `POST` this form to the PHP script containing the `insertRecord()` function. First you need to modify the `action` attribute in your `<form>` and point it to the `.php` script that has this function, then you simply do something like this:

```
$cmpny = new Company();
$cmpny->insertRecord($_POST);
```

Comment: Adnan, thanks for your answer, I do have a book that I am reading also, I am trying to teach myself this stuff at the moment and the learning curve is pretty steap in the beginning I think. The function is part of a class Default_Table but this doesn't work, even when compining yours and cutebabs answers

Comment: @MartinNielsen , I'm sorry my friend. You have fundamental issues in the way you're writing your code, the way you're debugging it, the way you're asking questions. I highly doubt that you'll get any help here at this point. You have a learning path that must be taken step by step, jumping isn't such a great idea. I wish you the best, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way of getting your POST data into the $fieldarray.  Could be something as simple as:

```
function insertRecord ($fieldarray) {
   //the function you have above
}

insertRecord($_POST);
```

Of course this is depending on how the insertRecord function is set up to work and if it will recognize all the POST data in the way you have things set up.